# How can we fetch IAM users, their groups and policies?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

I need to fetch all the aws user's, their corresponding groups, policies and then if mfa is activated for them or not. Can anyone tell me how it can be done via aws cli or boto.

I have a script that fetches out just the all user's in aws.

```
  import boto3
    from boto3 import *
    import argparse

    access_key = ''
    secret_key = ''

    def get_iam_uses_list():
    client =  boto3.client('iam',
                aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
       my_list=list()
       iam_all_users = client.list_users(MaxItems=200)
       for user in iam_all_users['Users']:
        my_list.append(user['UserName'])
#

    for i in my_list:
        print i

#    print "read complete"
#
#    for i in my_list:
#        iam_user_policy=client.list_attached_user_policies(UserName=i)
#        for policy in iam_user_policy['AttachedPolicies']:
#               print "%s \t %s" %(i, policy['PolicyName'])

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('access_key', help='Access Key');
    parser.add_argument('secret_key', help='Secret Key');
    args = parser.parse_args()
    global access_key
    global secret_key
    access_key = args.access_key
    secret_key = args.secret_key
get_iam_uses_list()

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

Comment: What's the specific issue you are having a problem with exactly? You are off to a good start, you just need to add some more AWS API calls to your script to get the rest of the data you want.

Answer (score 21):

Here, I am using boto commands to do four operations -

1. List all the users
2. List policy attached to each user
3. List roles added to each user
4. List Mfa devices to see if MFA has been configured by User or not (Here I am not checking is MFA is not enabled, but checking if the device has been configured by a user or not.)

**Get IAM connection to AWS Account**

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id="XXX",aws_secret_access_key="XXX")
```

**Getting IAM Users**
This will print all the usernames. you can customize if you want to print other details as well.

```
users = client.list_users()
for key in users['Users']:
    print key['UserName']
```

**Getting List of Policy attached to each user**

```
for key in users['Users']:
    List_of_Policies =  client.list_user_policies(UserName=key['UserName'])
    for key in List_of_Policies['PolicyNames']:
        print key['PolicyName']
```

**Getting List of Groups attached to each user**

```
for key in users['Users']:
    List_of_Groups =  client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=key['UserName'])
       for key in List_of_Groups['Groups']:
           print key['GroupName']
```

**Checking if MFA Device is configured or not**

```
for key in users['Users']:
    List_of_MFA_Devices = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=key['UserName'])
    for key in List_of_MFA_Devices['MFADevices']:
          print key
```

You can further check if List_of_MFA_Devices['MFADevices'] is empty or not. If empty, then MFA Device is not configured.

If you want to add output as List of Dict where each index will contain dict have value pairs for userName, Groups, Policy, isMFA_flag_configured or not. Use the following code -

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id="XXXX",aws_secret_access_key="YYY")
users = client.list_users()
user_list = []
for key in users['Users']:
    result = {}
    Policies = []
    Groups=[]

    result['userName']=key['UserName']
    List_of_Policies =  client.list_user_policies(UserName=key['UserName'])

    result['Policies'] = List_of_Policies['PolicyNames']

    List_of_Groups =  client.list_groups_for_user(UserName=key['UserName'])

    for Group in List_of_Groups['Groups']:
        Groups.append(Group['GroupName'])
    result['Groups'] = Groups

    List_of_MFA_Devices = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=key['UserName'])

    if not len(List_of_MFA_Devices['MFADevices']):
        result['isMFADeviceConfigured']=False   
    else:
        result['isMFADeviceConfigured']=True    
    user_list.append(result)

for key in user_list:
    print key
```

Output for the above code -

> {'userName': 'user1', 'Groups': ['grp1','grp2'], 'Policies':['policy1','policy2], 'isMFADeviceConfigured': False/True}
>
> {'userName': 'user2', 'Groups': ['grp1','grp2'], 'Policies': ['policy1','policy2], 'isMFADeviceConfigured': False/True}

Comment: thanks for your efforts.
But how can we get these in csv format
or may be print a dictionary >> name: value
or may be comma separated like below
Username, groups, policies or mfa

Comment: nope it isn't working unfortunately

it is just listing our user names that too not all of them

i needed output like

USERNAME, GROUP NAME, MFA 
something like this. I am trying to edit it. but failing.

Comment: Which credentials are you using - That credentials should be generated through user which have all required permission.

Comment: you can get the values as a dictionary , where I am printing the value, you can create a list or dictionary

Comment: i wnt to print it out for all the users of my company's aws account
I am using my credentials & how can i create a list of dictionary?

Comment: Do you have all required permissions? As you said you are not getting all user names? What error are you getting ? Changing the Answer in some time to store the result in Dict.

Comment: yes i have the required permission
when i editted MaxItems=200 then i got all usernames>

and please can you fetch out data Like
USERNAME, GROUPS, MFA, POLICIES

Comment: for your new script : thanks a lot :)
however i am getting this error ---- 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yo.py", line 14, in <module>
    Policies.append(Policy['PolicyName'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Thank you, You helped me when i needed it the most. i know basic/avg boto. How can i get proficient in boto. Any good tutorial or videos may be??I have also started learning python.