# Retrieve UserName from User ID - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function in an admin account that is triggered by an SQS queue, which receives messages from an SNS topic in a managed account, triggered by a compliance change for a Config Rule ("access-keys-rotated") in this same managed account.

I have noticed that the messages received from SNS only include the IAM User ID, not a User Name. In order to apply a policy/role to a user programmatically I have to have the UserName parameter.

Is there a way to resolve UserName from User ID that I just haven't stumbled upon yet? I've poured over the boto IAM API docs but every call I can think of to make requires a UserName.

Alternatively, is there a better way of architecting this workflow so that it is reliable AND provides me with the UserName for an IAM user?

Comment: hmm does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073435/how-can-we-fetch-iam-users-their-groups-and-policies

Comment: @BanjoObayomi Unfortunately not really, I would like to avoid having to iterate over all users to determine which userID belongs to whom.