# How to get policy document for aws managed policy of a iam user in python boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, policy

I'm able to retrieve the policy document for inline policies by "get_user_policy()" client. Is there any way to retrieve policy documents for AWS managed policies of IAM user..?

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
policy = iam.get_user_policy(UserName="<string>",PolicyName = "<string>")
doc = dict((k,response[k]) for k in ['PolicyDocument']if k in policy)
print(doc)
```

It seems like we can get a policy document of managed policy using its arn. But I'm not sure how to get arn for all the managed policies which were attached to particular IAM user.

So, How to get **the policy document for aws managed policy of iam user** in python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created one user called test1 and attached IAMReadOnlyAccess and PowerUserAccess. The catch was ARN difference for AWS managed policy and customer managed policy. [For more info.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html)

```
import boto3

iam_res = boto3.resource('iam')
user = iam_res.User('test1')

policy_iterator = user.attached_policies.all()

for each in policy_iterator:
    if each.arn.startswith('arn:aws:iam::aws'):
        print(each.default_version.document)
```

Here is the output.

```
{'Statement': [{'Action': ['iam:GenerateCredentialReport',
                           'iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails',
                           'iam:Get*',
                           'iam:List*',
                           'iam:SimulateCustomPolicy',
                           'iam:SimulatePrincipalPolicy'],
                'Effect': 'Allow',
                'Resource': '*'}],
 'Version': '2012-10-17'}
{'Statement': [{'Effect': 'Allow',
                'NotAction': ['iam:*', 'organizations:*', 'account:*'],
                'Resource': '*'},
               {'Action': ['iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole',
                           'iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole',
                           'iam:ListRoles',
                           'organizations:DescribeOrganization',
                           'account:ListRegions'],
                'Effect': 'Allow',
                'Resource': '*'}],
 'Version': '2012-10-17'}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use the following link for getting all policies attached to a user.
  [fetch users and policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073435/how-can-we-fetch-iam-users-their-groups-and-policies)
- then to get all the policy documents you can use

  [get_account_authorization_details](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_account_authorization_details)